# Structured Streaming in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Am trying to stream data from another server to HBase and be able to define different column families in Python. I have looked around in the Spark docs and only seeing:

```py
writestream.format('jdbc').start('jdbc:///')
```

How can I have the same implementations to write directly to HBase with the ability to map data to different column families?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your data to HBase using `foreach` (Scala or Java): http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach